Puppet noop based on AWS EC2 tag?
We are using the puppet-enc-ec2 ENC module to designate the role and environment of our puppet nodes via their AWS EC2 tags.
Is there any way to enforce noop via EC2 tag?  Another module or something?  Some nice piece of code I haven't been able to find yet?
Running Open Source Puppet v7
TIA!
I tried setting a noop:true tag on the instance.  I didn't expect that to work, and it doesn't.  My searches have not resulted in anything promising yet.


Is there any way to enforce noop via EC2 tag?

Probably.
In the first place, puppet-enc-ec2 documents that it produces the effect that

all EC2 Tags are made available to Puppet as trusted Top Level Variables with the ec2_tag_ prefix.

That means you can access the tag values inside your Puppet manifests.
To make use of that, you propose

Another module or something?

As a matter of fact, yes.  Maybe.  You seem to be looking for trlinkin-noop.  That provides a function noop() that, when called, makes all resources in the current scope noop (disclaimer: I have not used this module or its function personally).  For the particular behavior you want, I imagine you would put appropriate code at top scope in your site manifest to perform whatever tests you want on the target node's EC2 tags, and when the conditions are right, call noop().
There is a potential issue, however: this module is a bit old, and the metadata for the most recent version on the Forge report compatibility only through Puppet 5.  However, there is an open issue and associated pull request at its GitHub repo for extending compatibility through Puppet 8. Thus, although you may not be able to just pull down a version from the Forge, it wouldn't take too much work to get one that supposedly will serve.
